# cannot ping aws ec2 server or launch webpage after port 80/443 setup

Tags: amazon-ec2

I created a simple web application on AWS ec2 ubuntu instance, but was unable to access the webpage by ip and port from other machines. The application binds on 0.0.0.0:80, and this port has been added into ufw allowing list. Within the aws control panel, I also added 80 to the rule lists.

Currently, I could access the port 22 by `telnet ip 22` but no way to get responses from `ping ipaddress`, it shows `request timeout`. It also blocks on `telnet ip 80` without any responses.

Any ideas? Really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

here are some troubleshooting tips.

#### Check if the web application is actually running

you can do this simply by doing a `telnet ip 80` from the instance itself

#### disable the internal firewall

try disabling the firewall inside the instance, see whether it's working.

#### ping

In order for ping to work, enable ICMP protocol in your AWS security group

Comment: Glad to be of help
 Approve the answer if are happy